# Different class version with same name in different files

Tags: c++, file, class

I have two versions of a same class in two different files (A.cpp, A.h, B.cpp, B.h) in all files the class has the same name but different internal implementation.

My idea is to switch from one version to the other just by changing the name of the .h file at #include, so I shouldn't have to change anything else in the code (both version's methods have the same signature and same properties)

The A.h and B.h are never included at the same time.

The problem is that no matter what include file I use always A version is executed. I know that when I include B.h at least it is compiled (by putting some code error they are shown at compilation time)

Can this be done? or this is breaking some rules of C++? I think that this should not break One Definition Rule because I'm not using A.h and B.h at the same time.

Comment: The question is how are you linking the object files? Just adjusting the include is not going to work.

Comment: If you include B.h and link against B.o, you should be fine.  How are you linking?  But if the api for the class is consistent, then A.h and B.h should be identical; why are they different?

Comment: The header file you include is not going to matter as much as the actual code you are linking against.

Comment: You are doing it the hard way, I would have defined an Abstract class and inherited two classes from it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is **not to link** the old file into final executable. That way only the new implementation will be available.

Answer (score 2):

What I'll often do is mangle the version into a namespace, and use that.
Something along the lines of:

```
namespace Xyz_A {   //  In A.h
//  Define version A
}

namespace Xyz = Xyz_A;
```

; in `B.h`, use `_B` instead.

This way, you would write `Xyz::...` in your program, but the external
symbols will have `Xyz_A` or `Xyz_B` mangled into them.  But in my 
option, this is really more a protection against errors.  I'll arrange
things in my makefiles so that whatever switches between `A.h` and `B.h`
also causes the executable to link against the appropriate library, and
not against the other.

Comment: Indeed, putting the two versions in separate name spaces allows you compile both versions of the class into the same executable.  In addition to simplifying the build process, it allows you to write a run-time switch between versions (this might be useful for choosing the class version based on settings in a configuration file or the command line).

Comment: @AndréCaron You can't switch between namespaces at runtime.  Namespaces are purely a compile and link time resolution.  (I use the different namespaces to detect errors: compile against one version, and like, dynamically or otherwise, against another.)

Comment: Of course you can't.  However, you can write a simple switch such as `return (use_version_A?:new Xyz_A::Foo():new Xyz_B::Foo());`.  This can't be done if you switch them out with the build process.

Answer (score 0):

If the header files are identical it would be easier just to have one header and 2 different implementations files. That would reduce your problem to just linking with the right object file. This also reduces the chance of subtle bugs should your headers ever diverge.

A better solution would, of course, something that does not depend on the build system but uses language facilities to change code at compile time, like a template.

Comment: Why would templates be better?  Version management is a typical case of something that is best managed by the build system.

Comment: @James I didn't have the impression that he has two different versions but really just two different implementations of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the correct library to match the header file.

I would suggest looking into the proxy design pattern so you can include both class A and B. Then you can use the proxy to choose which class function to use during runtime.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern